# qt custom qstyle for qtabbar

Tags: c++, qt

I am using the following tab style for drawing tabbar text horizontally for 
east tab position. The text is drawn ok, as long as i dont set any margin for 
QTabBar::tab. In that case the text orientation remains vertical with strange offset.

```
class TabStyle : public QProxyStyle {
public:
  explicit TabStyle(Qt::Orientation orientation, QStyle *baseStyle = 0)
      : QProxyStyle(baseStyle), mOrientation(orientation) {}
  void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *option,
                   QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const {
    if (element == CE_TabBarTabLabel) {
      if (const QStyleOptionTab *tab =
              qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionTab *>(option)) {
        QStyleOptionTab opt(*tab);
        opt.shape = QTabBar::RoundedNorth;
        return QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, &opt, painter, widget);
      }
    }
    QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
  }

private:
  const Qt::Orientation mOrientation;
};

class TabWidget : public QTabWidget {
public:
  explicit TabWidget(QWidget *parent = 0,
                     Qt::Orientation orientation = Qt::Horizontal)
      : QTabWidget(parent) {
    QTabBar *tabBar = new QTabBar;
    tabBar->setStyle(new TabStyle(orientation));
    setTabBar(tabBar);
  }
};
```

Comment: maybe you can add also the picture how it should look and how it looks.. 
just shot in the dark - what about using setBaseStyle - maybe it will fill in some missing gaps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you Qt style sheets ? In the designer you could check it on the fly and you don't need write any code for that.

Comment: I didnt find any option to set text orientation to horizontal, when tabbar is positioned on the right side of the tabwidget. Is it possible?